# Why image and text not centering in flexbox subsection of my code in @media queries?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Under @media query, I am trying to center image and text under it but my code is not working. `text-align:center;` or `maring: 0 auto;align-items: center; justify-content: center;` I have tried too. What is the wrong I am doing? Please help. Here is the code:

```css
    .intro{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /*to set auto change row to column of its child sections*/
    padding: 5px;
    /*height: 400px;*/
    
}
.welcomeText{
    color: black;
    flex: 4;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px 40px; 
    
}
.welcomeText h1{
    margin: 50px 80px;
    font-family: 'Bodoni Moda', serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.welcomeText p{
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
.viewProjectsButton{
    background-color:antiquewhite;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-top:15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 18px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    transition: .2s;
}
.viewProjectsButton:hover{
   background-color:cadetblue;
}
#wordProfile{
    color:navajowhite;
}
.imgAuthor{
/*  background-image: url("../img/author.jpg");
    background-size: auto;*/
    flex: 2;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
  background-color:blue;

    
}
.imgAuthor img{
    border-radius: 37% 56% 47% 36% / 39% 48% 48% 36% ;
    width: 300px;
    height: 295px;
    

}
.autherName{
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 25px;
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body{
    background-color:green;
  }
    .imgAuthor img{
 margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .autherName{
    text-align: center; 
    }   
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>

    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div class="intro">
    <!--intro will have 2 blocks-->
        <div class="welcomeText"> <h1>Welcome to My <span id="wordProfile"> Profile</span></h1>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, earum vero.
            </h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
            <a href="#"><button class="viewProjectsButton">View Projects</button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="imgAuthor">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="author-image"/>
            <h2 class="autherName">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
        </div>
        
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right, but I found that you missed one last "}" at the end of your media query. That is the reason why your media query is not working.

I also removed the original margin-left: 25px of the .autherName, setting a margin left outside the media query will prevent you to centralize your text when the width is less than 300px in your case.

Remarks: Please be noted that you currently don't have any class set for the img itself, you are only editing **the container** of both the img and .autherName, I am not sure if that is what you really way to do it, anyway, please see if this help:

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*to set auto change row to column of its child sections*/
  padding: 5px;
  /*height: 400px;*/
}

.welcomeText {
  color: black;
  flex: 4;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 40px;
}

.welcomeText h1 {
  margin: 50px 80px;
  font-family: 'Bodoni Moda', serif;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.welcomeText p {
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

.viewProjectsButton {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  transition: .2s;
}

.viewProjectsButton:hover {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

#wordProfile {
  color: navajowhite;
}

.imgAuthor {
  /*    background-image: url("../img/author.jpg");
    background-size: auto;*/
  flex: 2;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  display:flas;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.imgAuthor img {
  border-radius: 37% 56% 47% 36% / 39% 48% 48% 36%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 295px;
}

.autherName {
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .imgAuthor img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .autherName {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="intro">
    <!--intro will have 2 blocks-->
    <div class="welcomeText">
      <h1>Welcome to My <span id="wordProfile"> Profile</span></h1>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, earum vero.
      </h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
      <a href="#"><button class="viewProjectsButton">View Projects</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="imgAuthor">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        alt="author-image" />
      <h2 class="autherName">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. It is still on the left side. I set "background-color:blue;" under .imgAuthor to see the image alignment properly in my Codepan  . Re. autherName class has a text, at lest it should be centered but not there as you an see.

Comment: You are welcome, I can see the new background you made, but the closing curly bracket is still missing at the end of the CSS as I am checking, have you tried that out yet?

Comment: The code snippet I did above is able to centralize the h2 text when the browser's width is less than 300px, you could check out the effect by clicking the Run code snippet and the Full page button. However it wasn't looked centralized because the h1 block(Welcome to My) has a fixed margin, so it prevent the whole site to shrink together.

Comment: I run the snippet but as you can see in the attached image both image and text(h2) is in left position. I am running both Firefox and Chrome but same found. As you say you have a different (centralize view of h2) view, is may browser creating problems? here is the link of the image how I can see -
https://ibb.co/sbT4sWw

Comment: That should not be the browser's difference. For more accurate checking, I would suggest you to use the [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) (For Firefox and Chrome, the shortcut will be Ctrl+Shift+M if you are using Windows) and input the 300px size for width, these are the screenshots from my browser: 
[More than 300px width](https://ibb.co/5TLHbt9)
[Close to 300px width](https://ibb.co/KxSM5Vj)
[Less than 300px width](https://ibb.co/gVkYJxk)

Comment: Thank you. I have to switch media query to @media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 500px) to get the targeted 300px. It looks shrinking my browser in desktop was not getting to 300px or less. Switching to media query "@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 500px)" solved my problem. Thanks again for your valuable  time to share with me. Have nice day.

Comment: You are very welcome my friend, I am glad that I could help.